# curl from docker ubuntu image

Tags: ubuntu, curl, docker

I have created docker image which is based on the ubuntu image, and contains java and tomcat.

```
FROM dockerfile/ubuntu

#java, tomcat

EXPOSE 80
```

Then:

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 <image>
```

Without running tomcat, just running image and attaching to it - I try to make request to any site. For example:

```
curl google.com
```

Results connection refused:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection refused
```

What could cause this problem?

Image is running on Amazon Linux, if it matters.

Comment: what is the output in the logs: `docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>` - are you starting up tomcat in the container?

Comment: I am not running tomcat, just bash is executed and nothing else is done

Comment: So what do you expect to connect to???

Comment: When inside the container I want to be able to curl something from the outside world. Unless if I run application it fails, because it needs to access internet.

Comment: That is your issue, you cannot connect to tomcat until you have run tomcat.

Comment: I think that you might be misunderstanding how docker works - only one application may work at a time, if you start up the container and run /bin/bash then you do not have tomcat running.

Comment: I think you'll get more help if you drop the attitude, even if you're frustrated. What have you tried as far as debugging the issue? For example, do `nslookup` or `traceroute` tell you anything interesting? It seems that you may have a DNS issue.

Comment: Question isn't worded as well as it could be, it looks like Sandris' issue is that their containers cannot connect to the internet at all.

Without knowing more about your setup all I can say is check to make sure your network settings are correct. Ex) Network bridging may not be an option, so you may have to make sure your IP forwarding settings are correct on the Amazon Linux side.

Comment: You also mentioned Amazon Linux, is this running inside a VPC? This might just be a security group issue.

Comment: I was confused by the original post which stated "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused" - anyhow moving past this, the container should have access to your internet - is there any chance you have dns problems? try `getent hosts google.com` - see what that returns.

Comment: getent hosts google.com returns - 2a00:1450:4013:c00::66 google.com. From the instance which is running docker everything works fine, so it is docker issue.

Answer (score 0):

Deployed the same image on aws ubuntu 14.04 and everything works.